# DB for multiple entity high performance tagging

Tags: database, performance, tags, metadata, normalization

I'm designing a database for a social app and am trying to determine if my approach is 1) going to perform well, and 2) properly normalized?

My research on tag query performance and db design concluded that a single tags table with full text index search yields the best performance.

See this:  http://tagging.pui.ch/post/37027746608/tagsystems-performance-tests

I know I could (and should from a pure normalization standpoint) put the tags in a separate table with a key per tag, but performance would suffer as the db grows large (according to the linked article). Tag searching is a key component to my app and must perform well.

The below structure illustrates a basic approach I've devised that uses a bridge metadata table, and I expect many more "object tables" to be bridged using this single table, but I provide only a couple to give the idea:

Users Table: UserID PK, UserName, Etc

Blogs Table: BlogID PK, UserID FK, BlogTxt, Etc

Photos Table: PhotoID PK, UserID FK, PhotoPath, Etc

Metadata Table: MetadataID PK, UserID FK, ObjectTable (Posts or Blogs), ObjectID FK (PostID or BlogID), Tags (tag1,tag2,tag3)

In addition to the above questions, I'm also interested to know if there are better alternatives. I'm new to db design so please excuse any serious ignorance on the proper way of doing this.  Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

> My research on tag query performance and db design concluded that a single tags table with full text index search yields the best performance.

This is actually incorrect...

The best performance you can get is to switch to a database engine that has an array type and bitmap index scans, maintain an aggregate of your tags in an [int[] array](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html) column using triggers, and add an appropriate index (gin, gist, rtree) on it.

This allows to write queries (Postgres syntax below) such as:

```
create index on posts using gin (tags);

-- bitmap AND/OR index scan on posts
-- has 1 or 2 or 3 or any of 4, 5, 6 without 7 or 8
select *
from posts
where tags && array[1,2,3]
or tags && array[4,5,6] and not tags && array[7,8]
```

The above will blow away any potential optimization you can think of using MySQL.

Comment: Downvote because of your tone and assertion that any database that doesn't support array columns isn't a *real* database engine. The question was posed in a platform-agnostic manner, and so should the answer be.

Comment: Which is fair enough. I was editing it in the background while you were voting, because I thought the same. :-P

Comment: Hehe. I think it's neutral enough now. :-)

Comment: Would my db design need to change with the use of an alternate Engine?  Also, any thoughts on the whether the above approach is normalized? Finally, please forgive my ignorance, but being new to db design, much of what is proposed is well over my head, although I'm not adverse to researching and looking into your approach further. Having said that, it's important to me that what ever I implement has general wide-spread community peer support available. I lean toward the default mysql engine, but don't want to compromise future performance in the process. Is it just a bad idea to use my design?

Comment: Postgres and MySQL aren't too different when it comes to the more commonly used things; Postgres is a bit stricter. Postgres allows for spacial and full text indexing without sacrificing ACID compliance. And it is features more pl/ languages, more types, better query planning, and much more. Given a choice I'd never go with MySQL, but at the end of the day this is a matter of taste. Anyway, your design is not bad. It's just that... try the above query with your design, 1M posts, and 3M randomly assigned links to 100k tags. My suggested query will have acceptable performance; yours won't.